# Does anyone know how to position a hyperlink box on a web banner to be position-specific to pixels as opposed to 'left' or 'right'?

Tags: html, css, class, web

I need to change the position of a box that has a hyperlink that takes me to order a product. The code that is currently producing the web banner is as follows:

```html
...

<img src="assets/file/home-page-slider/gofogwebbanner.png" width="1470" height="380" border="0" usemap="#map" />
<map name="map">
<div class="banner-text-03-left"><a class="home-slider-button" href="products/anti-viral-room-fogger-200ml-canister" title="Order now">Order now</a></div></map>
...
```

I know that I can change the 'left' to be 'right' and that moves my hyperlink box to the right side of the banner, but I would live to place it, preferably to the pixel if I could, around the middle bottom of the banner.

NOTE: I am working on QVS3 and I am editing our live website that is already built. A link to the website is here and the banner in question is the 'GoFog' ad on the first banner slide when you visit the website. Link: https://www.ehmltd.co.uk/

I am sure this is like ABCs to someone who has the know-how, but it is proving difficult for me at the minute. Any help would be appreciated! I will reply pretty much instantly to all/any help I can get, so feel free to ask me questions if you need more info.

Comment: Your code seems broken since there is no closing `</map>`. Could you check this and update the example code to be valid?

Comment: Updated. In this particular instance it doesn't impact the result of the code. Any idea on the question itself?

Comment: See my answer below

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that was you also. I replied to that a couple of mins ago. It returned the image but didn't give me the box with the hyperlink at all... are you familiar with CMS management within QVS3?

Comment: I'm not, sorry.

Comment: No worries. I replaced the <div /> inside the <map /> using <area /> and it didn't work unfortunately. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a `<div />` inside the [`<map />`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map) use `<area />`

```html
<map name="map">
  <area shape="rect" coords="25,25,75,75" href="products/anti-viral-room-fogger-200ml-canister">
</map>
<img src="assets/file/home-page-slider/gofogwebbanner.png" width="1470" height="380" border="0" usemap="#map">
```

Comment: I put this code in and it just returned the photo of the banner that I have already created and got rid of the box hyperlink altogether...

Comment: Well, an image map ([area](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Element/area)) is not meant to place full HTML content on an image. But the hyperlink is still there as you can see in my example. If you still want to do that, you need to use something else.

Comment: Would it help to put the button styling directly in the image underneath so that an `<area />` would suffice? Otherwise you might have to stick with absolute positioning, I guess.

Comment: In my code in the question, if I change 'left' to 'right', that will change the hyperlink box to the right side of the web banner. However, 'top' and 'bottom' absolute positions make the box disappear... I just want to place the hyperlink box, say, 50px above the bottom of the web banner, and make in centred, but I'm stuck.